# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(1+1/n\big)^n$ is equal to e

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

How do I prove the following limit without using the derivative.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(1+1/n\big)^n$$

I have tried using the Binomial theorem but I haven't got too far. I have proved that the limit is between 2 and 3 and that it is convergent. Also if I logaritmate the whole equation I can't get anywhere without applying the derivative. And it doesn't get me anywhere if I try the Epsilon-delta proof.

$$\ln(y) = \ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(1+1/n\big)^n\right)$$

Comment: What are you taking as the definition of $e$?

Comment: I take e as 2.71828...

Comment: And what comes after the dots?  This is not a definition, it's just an approximation.

Comment: the expression you give here is exactly the original definition of $e$.

Comment: So you say that I should just say that 1 + 1 + 1/2! +1/3! + ... + 1/n! is e and prove this limit ?

Comment: Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_2), where it is explained how $\displaystyle\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\to\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written is often taken as the definition of $e$.  You know that it converges, and the number it converges to is what we call $e$.

Another formula, useful in approximating $e$ (because it converges quickly), is this one:
$$e = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}+\cdots$$

To show that this is equal to what you've written, we should start with the binomial theorem.  The $k$-th term of $(1+1/n)^n$ is ${n\choose k} n^{-k}$, or $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k! n^k} = \frac{1\cdot(1-1/n)\cdots(1-(k+1)/n)}{k!}$.  If $k$ remains fixed, and $n\to \infty$, this is just $\frac{1}{k!}$.

This is not quite a proof, but it's a good start for comparing the two expressions.  Once you know the above power series, you can compute that $e=2.7182818284\ldots$ or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E(n)=(1+1/n)^n.$ Notice that $$\ln(E(n))=\frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{1/n}.$$
Therefore the limit as $n\to \infty$ of $\ln E(n))$ is
$$
\lim_{1/n\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+1/n)-\ln(1)}{1/n}
$$
which is the derivative of $\ln(x)$ near $1$ and therefore equals $1$.  Using continuity of the natural logarithm, this shows that 
$$
\ln\lim_{n\to\infty}E(n)=1.
$$

Therefore the limit must be $e$ where $e$ is the unique number whose natural log is $1$.

Comment: For these purposes, one can either define $\ln x$ as the inverse of $\operatorname{exp}(x)$, or as $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt$.

Comment: To avoid circularity, use the second definition and the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute the derivative of ln(x) at 1.

Comment: I slightly prefer defining $\operatorname{exp}(x)$ as the solution to the differential equation $f(0)=1$, $f'(x)=f(x)$, and computing the derivative of its inverse using the chain rule.  But these are pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac 1n)^n\\
=&\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n\log(1+1/n)}\\
=&e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log(1+1/n)}\\
=&e^{\lim_{t\to 0}\log(1+t)/t}\\
=&e^{1/1}\\
=&e
\end{align}
$$
Explanations:

$1$.Given

$2$.$e^{\log x}=x$

$3$.$\lim a^x=a^{\lim x}$

$4$.$ \,t=\frac 1n$

$5$.Limit Evaluation

$6$.Simplification

Answer (score 0):

Before at all you have to prove that :
$s_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ converges into a finite value.

How? 
Firstly prove that $s_n$ is monotone-increasing sequence.

Secondly prove that is a upper bounded sequence.

If this 2 statements are true then $s_n$ converges into a finite value (important theorem)
and then we call it e

After We wonder how to aproximate e. But that question was answered by the others above.