# How can you prove $ \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ {k} < \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} \right ) ^ {k+1} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm re-reading my old math books, and froze on the following theorem:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right ) ^ {x} = e $$
$$ e = 2,71... $$

I started thinking about it, and went on to prove:

$$ \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ {k} < \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k+1} \right ) ^ {k+1} $$

..but couldn't.

Please help.

Comment: That's usually the definition of $e$. What definition would you like to start with?

Comment: Somone will soon fine the correct duplicate for this question. This has been asked and answered here hundreds of times before.

Comment: Just asking to clarify, is the OP asking for a proof of the limit result or the monotonicity of $\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right ) ^ {k}$ ?

Comment: It depends a little bit on what you are assuming. If you start from $e^x$ being defined as the solution to $y'=y,y(0)=1$, then you can derive logarithm rules in order to prove that $f(x)=\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right )^x$ is increasing. Monotonicity tells you that the limit exists (possibly it could be infinite), and that it is the same as the limit along any sequence going to $+\infty$. So you can now reduce to $\left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n$. Then there are many ways to deal with this (the binomial theorem, for example).

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254335/prove-that-5-2-e-3/254339#254339

Comment: Better(?) [dupe]( http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420018/23353).

Comment: @AndreyKaipov you lost me.

Comment: @AndreyKaipov, uh-huh, do you mean that is [exactly the original definition of e](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/630658/203530)? I changed the title, because I didn't know.